# How to correctly add a spell check enabled Textbox in WPF at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Situation: I want to add textboxes that are spell-check enabled at runtime to a WPF window. The system is running at german settings ("de") and the spell check language should be English.
The following code only works as expected from that moment, when one textbox is focused.

```
private void AddTextBoxButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();            
        InputLanguageManager.SetInputLanguage(txtBox, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en"));
        txtBox.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
        stackPanel.Children.Add(txtBox);
}
```

Example: I klick the "Add textbox" button. A textbox is added to the stackpanel. But this textbox knows only the german language for spell checking. If this box is focused and I add another textbox to the stackpanel, the new textbox supports spell checking in english.

[Screenshot demonstrating the spell check example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNmkl.jpg)

What is the reason for this behaviour? I would expect, that every textbox added to the stackpanel at runtime would use the english spell checking right from the start.

Here is the XAML code.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfSpellCheckStackOverflow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Name="AddTextBoxButton" Content="Add a textbox" Click="AddTextBoxButton_Click" Margin="4" ></Button>
        <StackPanel Name="stackPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4"></StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spell check language for a TextBox control is selected based on the following rules in this order:

1. xml:lang attribute is used (only if specified)
2. current input language
3. culture of the current thread

Solution for you is to use the following:

```
txtBox.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("en");
```

instead of:

```
InputLanguageManager.SetInputLanguage(txtBox, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en"));
```

Comment: Did you change the input language in between the clicks?

Comment: No. The input language is only changed by the code as it is displayed above. I just click into the different textboxes.

Comment: I just tried your example and if I change current language between first and second text box is added, I get exactly the behavior from your screenshot.

Comment: Is the first text box also created with the same add function that is called by actually clicking on it or by another function?

Comment: It seems that command InputLanguageManager.SetInputLanguage(..) is not influencing the spell check at all.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The keyboard layout for both textboxes is english (german keyboards have z and y swapped) but besides of that, spell checking does not occur in english for the first box. Your answer sounds like you have spell checking in english for both fields right from the start if you don't change the language? Concerning your question: Yes it is the same method triggered every time I cklick the button.

Comment: I now had the time to check your solution and as far as I can say this works fine. Thank you very much!
To bad that most of the search results concerning this topic contain the code that I used for my (faulty) implementation.